# Как "это по-русски" 2: купальник раздельный и купальник сдельный

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование

Читаю: "Надев простой СДЕЛЬНЫЙ спортивный купальник...", смотрю значение слова "сдельный": "прил. Основанный на оплате по количеству выработанной продукции.", сомневаюсь и смотрю в интернете: "Сдельные купальники в ОТТО! - Доступная мода из Европы." - не эталон, но имеет место быть. Получается, что это синоним слов совместный, закрытый, сплошной. Хотя, мне при употреблении слова "раздельный" понятно что с купальником сделали - его разделили. Со словом "сдельный" проявляется бессмыслица, на мой взгляд. "Сдельный купальник" это по-русски?

Comment: Бывают и сдельно-раздельные — Монокини, и беременные: «Я на море буду брать раздельный, просто на солнце не загорать пузиком, а беременные купальники какие-то страшненькие». Это не по-русски. Птичий язык.

Answer (score 1):

Купальники бывают слитные, сплошные, закрытые, эти слова имеют смысл. Наилучший вариант противопоставления: слитный и раздельный.

Сдельный (в этом случае) - совершенно бессмысленное слово, тем не менее оно тоже встречается у не очень разборчивых пользователей с плохим слухом. А потом и все привыкнут, и будут у нас сдельные купальники.

Comment: Согласна. Реклама - штендер рядом с нашим офисом продвигает чулочно - носочную продукцию: колготки, носки и следки. По мне, так эти самые "следки" на слух не очень. Проводила опрос среди сотрудников. Никто не удивился, что данную форму изделия называют не подследники, а следки в простонародье.  Все логично и объяснимо. Но реклама получилась "малограмотной". И вот эта малограмотность ползет из всех щелей. Обидно...